# Remote debugging MVC 6 application: Symbols not loaded.

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, remote-debugging

I've built an MVC 6 application that sits on top of the .NETCLR (ASP .Net 4.5) and not the CoreCLR (.Net Core) as shown by the setting displayed Figure 1. I've deployed this application to Azure and am now attempting to carry out some remote debugging.

In order to enable remote debugging I ensured that the "Remote Debugging" setting in the azure management portal was set to 'On' as displayed in Figure 2. and ensured that the 'Enable Just my code' and 'Require source files to match the original version' were unchecked in Visual Studios Debug options as displayed in Figure 3. However the breakpoints are still not being hit: "No Symbols have been loaded for this document" as shown in Figure 4.

I've also checked to see if I need to attached anything else to the process but all I see is what is displayed in Figure 5 when selecting my remote web application as the qualifier. I think the w3wp.exe is the only thing I need here as its not running on top of .CoreCLR but the .NETCLR.

Not sure what else I need to do to get this working.

Figure 1: Framework setting in project.json. 
 [image: Framework setting in project.json]

Figure 2: Azure Remote Debugging setting.
[image: Azure Remote Debugging setting]

Figure 3: Visual studio debug options. 
[image: Visual studio debug options]

Figure 4: Breakpoint error.
[image: Breakpoint error]

Figure 5: Available Processes to attach to. 
[image: Available Processes to attach to]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I think I've found the issue... I was going along the right lines when looking at the available processes to attach to (Figure 5), I was expecting to see the dnx.exe option out the available process however this has now been removed in the RC2 release, I should be looking for the exact process name. Which in my case is AzureBillingCost.exe. When attached to this process the issue is resolved.